# FastReport mvc GetParameter() returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fastreport

I have to initiate **fastreport** report and populate it into a new page. No problem yet! Report shows correctly.
But then I declared a parameter in *FastReport designer*, named **"CurrentDateTimeParam"**. This parameter aimed to display current Date and Time of report.

**NOTE:** this DateTime is not a regular DateTime (persian DateTime actually). so it has to be estimated by code.

So i decided to set it's value by `webReport.Report.SetParameterValue("CurrentDateTimeParam","Some String Here")`

in the *Controller*
a gain, the report shows correctly except that DateTime is not updated.  also

```
webReport.Report.GetParameter("CurrentDateTimeParam")
```

returns `NULL`. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may looks stupid but i finally resolve the problem by putting above line of code in some event trigger. like following:

```
webReport.Report.StartReport += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   webReport.Report.SetParameterValue("CurrentDateTimeParam","Some String Here");
}
```